# Is it meaningful to have abstract classes just for purpose of layering structure?

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-class, software-design

Assume a Java class (e.g. a helper class), which has a great bundle of methods that could be separated into different *layers*. By *layers*, I mean the design of clearer responsibilities for each class and a reduction of complexity. Is it meaningful in this case, by using abstract class, to achieve the goal, in the sense of clean code and software design?

I encountered the situation in a project where there is a helper class having too much complexity and simply too many rows. The class is somehow playing vital roles, acting as a kind of type helper assisting other objects to fetch and manipulate type information. Each time a new/existing type would need extra type info, this class comes into help, therefore becomes heavier and more complicated in implementing methods. Though I can surely categorize and separate those methods into many classes. I found there be a structural correlation between those methods. Please see the code example below:

Assume a Type can have some TypeProperty:s. Assume also in code that there are a Type class and a TypeProperty class, both with essential getters and setters, meanwhile a Helper class Helper.

```
public class Helper{

    static final T CONSTANT_A = new A(...);
    static final T CONSTANT_B = new B(...);

    final Type theType;

   //constructor etc.

    Type getType(){
        return theType;
    }

    Type getTypeByKey(Key typeKey){
        //...
    }

    Collection<TypeProperty> getPropertiesByType(Type t){
        //...
    }

    Collection<TypeProperty> getProperties(){
       return theType.getProperties();
    }

    TypeProperty findSpecificPropertyInTypeByKey(Key propertyKey){
        Set<TypeProperty> properties= theType.getProperties();
        //loop through the properties and get the property,  
        //else return null or cast exception if not found
    }

    boolean isTypeChangeable(){
        return findSpecificPropertyInTypeByKey().isChangeable();
    }

    //many more methods
}
```

I expect to refactor the Helper class so that the code is easier to maintain and expand, as well as, to be less complex. I think it is possible to separate the methods into different classes, however, this might lead to too many classes and the responsibilities are not straight-forward as they are not in a helper class(es). While in the meantime, the idea of utilizing abstract classes comes into my mind. Would it be meaningful then? Say that after refactoring, there would be

- a TopLevelHelper having methods revolving the type itself, e.g. isTypeChangeable & getType(), as well as, all Constants;
- a SecondLevelHelper extending TopLevelHelper, which bears the logics as middleware, e.g. getProperties and getPropertiesByType;
- a LastLevelHelper extending SecondLevelHelper, which does the concrete and detailed works, e.g. findSpecificPropertyInTypeByKey.

Though none of these classes would have abstract methods but concrete implementations since none of the methods in higher-level helpers would be overridden. It does not seem that such a design is appropriate usage of abstract classes, still, I feel it separates responsibilities into three layers. Should it be done like this or should other techniques be used in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

There's no definite answer of course, but I think you should stick with what you have. Abstract classes are mostly meaningful for implementing [template methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and similar patterns. Splitting a class on different hierarchy levels does feel weird in your case, because the methods do seem to belong to different groups, rather than different levels. If java allowed multiple inheritance, traits, or something similar, you could make the mixin classes.

However, a class with multiple methods is fine. Although OOP design guidelines often say you should limit your class to eg 5 method, you class seems more of a smart data structure than a class, and your methods are mostly accessors and properties. So, since they are simple and conceptually similar, there's no real problem having many of them. Java itself does it all the time (for example, see string & collection classes reference).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that layering is not a good approach.

From what you are saying about that 3 layers, they have different responsibilities. If all this 3 responsibilities are coded in the same class, it breaks the *Single Responsibility Principle*. So the solution that naturally follows is to split each one in its own class and use composition. By doing this you also adhere to the principle that says *composition is preferable to inheritance*.